# QThread dedicated to infinite loop

Tags: c++, qt

So i want to create a separared thread for my infinite while loop. How to fix the code below so it doesnt break the signal slot connection?

```
#include "gameloop.h"

GameLoop::GameLoop(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    timer = new QTimer;
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(mySlot()));
    timer->start(500);
    thread = new QThread();
    console = new Console;
    console->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();

    run();
}

GameLoop::~GameLoop()
{
    std::cout << "GameLoop() Destructor" << "\n";
}

void GameLoop::run()
{
     console->loop();
}



void GameLoop::mySlot()
{
    std::cout << "mySlot" << "\n";
}
```

Member function loop() in the class Console contains while(1).

Comment: try changing `run();` to `QTimer::singleShot(0, this, &GameLoop::run);` and have that `run()` be a slot.

Comment: But my interest is in why the infinite loop in the separate thread is still disrupring the signal slot system.

Comment: I do not know what are you talking about.

Comment: I meant to ask, why in the code above, the QTimer fires mySlot whenconsole->loop(); is commented out. Isnt it that putting something into a separate thread gives it "own life"? Yet calling console->loop() prvents mySlot from being fired

Comment: Is that the run method  is not executed in the thread where GameLoop lives but in the thread where GameLoop was created that is very different since you are using moveToThread. I assume that the GameLoop was created in the main thread so the run method is blocking the event-loop, the event-loop of Qt is what allows the operation of signals, timers, events, etc. For that reason it does not work, instead with my suggestion the run method would be executed in the thread where the GameLoop lives. Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: I've found solution and described in the answer. Kiss Kiss.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that solved my problem is as follows in the code below, this way the infinite loop is in a thread decicated to it:

```
#include "gameloop.h"
#include <QThread>
GameLoop::GameLoop(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    std::cout << "GameLoop thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId()  << "\n";
    timer = new QTimer;
    timer->start(3000);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(mySlot())); //timers

    thread1 = new QThread;

    console.moveToThread(thread1);
    thread1->start();
    connect(thread1, SIGNAL(started()), &console, SLOT(mySlotActivationLoop()));
}
```